# Living in basement

Tags: sentence-construction

How to mention that I am living in basement of new residence?

I have mentioned that

"I am living in the basement of new residential address" in visa application.

Is the above sentence correct?

Comment: Do you mean that your new address is a basement flat/apartment, or that you have moved into a house but are living in the basement while work is being done on the main house?

Comment: I mean there are three floors, basement, ground floor, first floor at my new residence. Yes i am relocated to new home. work is not under construction. Should i use lower ground instead of basement?

Comment: In my country, each apartment in a divided house would have an identifying number, but I know from experience that it is not the same everywhere. If you don't have an official address that states which floor you live on, yes, just say that you live in the basement.